# Windows form have a messagebox display when x-ing out of form?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-forms-designer

I'm wondering if there is any way to set up a windows form so that when the user clicks the red X button, instead of closing the form it will display a message box along the lines of "Are you sure you want to quit?" Is there a certian event in Windows form or some other work around I'd need to do?

Comment: I hate when some program asks me if I want to exit when I click the exit button. For what else reason I have clicked the close button? Seriously, I think your idea is wrong unless you have some unsaved data

Comment: it's going to only occur when a thread is still running, the main program collects and transfers data so it needs to warn users if they try and close mid-collection. Otherwise it won't do that because I agree with you whole-hearted that it's a pain in the butt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(Form1_FormClosing);
```

And:

```
void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("...","...", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel) == DialogResult.OK)
        e.Cancel = true;
}
```